# Python: How to read a table from word when it is in a text box?

Tags: python, pywin32, cpu-word

I have a table in a word document and I want to extract the information from it using Python. I am able to access tables from word documents using the code below, however, this time the table is in a text box.

How can I access a table if it is in a text box?

```
import win32com.client as win32
word.Documents.Open(filename) ###open word file
doc = word.ActiveDocument  
table = doc.Tables(1)
```

where table is the table, and I can access its information etc.

Kind regards,
Nima

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a solution using another python package `docx2python`.

```
from docx2python import docx2python
doc = docx2python(word_document_path)
doc_body = doc.body
table = doc_body[table_number]
table = pd.DataFrame(table)
```